# Speech + Audio Recording Same time (IllegalState Exception)

Tags: android, speech-recognition, audio-recording, illegalstateexception, mediarecorder

i have some problem when using device mic simuntaniously , When i have started mediarecorder for record audio and i am try to start recognizer intent for speech recognizer i am getting **IllegalStateException start failed: -38**

**Logcat**

> AudioRecord: start() status -38
>
> 10-10 11:25:11.180 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio
>   D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN 10-10 11:25:11.280
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio E/MainActivity:
>   setUpMediaRecorder: =>> /storage/emulated/0/audiofile.3gpp 10-10
>   11:25:11.320 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio
>   E/MainActivity: start: ==> Started Audio Recording 10-10 11:25:11.380
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio E/MediaRecorder: start
>   failed: -38 10-10 11:25:11.380
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio W/System.err:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException 10-10 11:25:11.380
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio W/System.err:     at
>   android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method) 10-10 11:25:11.380
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.techno_110.recordaudio.MainActivity.start(MainActivity.java:313)
>   10-10 11:25:11.380 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.techno_110.recordaudio.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:115)
>   10-10 11:25:11.380 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio
>   W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5214)
>   10-10 11:25:11.380 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20978) 10-10 11:25:11.390
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 10-10 11:25:11.390
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 10-10 11:25:11.390
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 10-10 11:25:11.390
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134) 10-10
>   11:25:11.390 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   10-10 11:25:11.390 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   10-10 11:25:11.390 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>   10-10 11:25:11.390 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 10-10
>   11:25:11.390 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio
>   E/MainActivity: recognize: ==> Started listening transactions 10-10
>   11:25:11.400 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT:
>   RecorderSource$1: Starting recording 10-10 11:25:11.410
>   23074-23864/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT:
>   AttachableHandler: Attached handler to current thread, sending 1
>   queued messages 10-10 11:25:11.420
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT:
>   CommandContextImpl: Creating command NMDP_ASR_CMD 10-10 11:25:11.420
>   23074-23117/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMSP_: [ResourceImpl]
>   loadResource 10-10 11:25:11.430
>   23074-23117/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMSP_: [NMSPSession]
>   Creating new SDK calllog tree 10-10 11:25:11.430
>   23074-23864/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio E/AudioRecord: start()
>   status -38 10-10 11:25:11.430
>   23074-23864/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio V/NMT:
>   MicrophoneRecorderSourceBase$2: Android audio system onMarkerReached
>   invoked 10-10 11:25:11.430
>   23074-23864/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio E/NMT:
>   MicrophoneRecorderSource: readBuffer() _recorder.read() didn't read
>   any audio!!! 10-10 11:25:11.430
>   23074-23864/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT:
>   MicrophoneRecorderSource: cleanup() stop _recorder. 10-10 11:25:11.430
>   23074-23864/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT:
>   MicrophoneRecorderSource: cleanup() release _recorder. 10-10
>   11:25:11.440 23074-23864/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT:
>   MicrophoneRecorderSource: handleSourceClosed() 10-10 11:25:11.440
>   23074-23117/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio I/NMSP:
>   [PDXTransactionImpl] appendLogToQueryBegin:
>   NMSPDefines.DEVICE_CMD_LOG_TO_SERVER_ENABLED is disabled 10-10
>   11:25:11.450 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT:
>   CommandContextImpl: Sending param REQUEST_INFO 10-10 11:25:11.450
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT:
>   CommandContextImpl: Sending param AUDIO_INFO 10-10 11:25:11.450
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT:
>   CommandContextImpl: Ending command 10-10 11:25:11.450
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT: AudioParam:
>   stream() 10-10 11:25:11.460
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT: AudioParam:
>   sourceClosed() 10-10 11:25:11.460
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT:
>   CommandContextImpl: [LATCHK] calling addAudioBuf() final 10-10
>   11:25:11.460 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT:
>   CommandContextImpl: stream audio last buffer [true] 10-10 11:25:57.070
>   23074-23869/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio E/NMSP:
>   [NetworkSystemOEM] Set Socket Option Exception -
>   [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException] Message - [SSL handshake
>   aborted: ssl=0xaf541e00: I/O error during system call, Connection
>   reset by peer] 10-10 11:25:57.080
>   23074-23117/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio E/NMSP: [XMode]
>   XMode.openSocketCallback() NETWORK_ERROR 10-10 11:25:57.080
>   23074-23117/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMSP_:
>   [NMASResourceImpl] onSessionDisconnected() reasonCode:9 10-10
>   11:25:57.080 23074-23117/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio E/NMT:
>   CommandContextImpl: Command Creation Failed [NMDP_ASR_CMD] 10-10
>   11:25:57.080 23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT:
>   TransactionStateStreaming: Streaming parameter: AUDIO_INFO is
>   cancelled. 10-10 11:25:57.080
>   23074-23074/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio D/NMT: AudioParam:
>   cancelStreaming() 10-10 11:25:57.080
>   23074-23117/com.example.techno_110.recordaudio W/NMT:
>   CloudServicesImpl: Connection failed reasonCode [10]

I had searched a lot to overcome this problem , please someone help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android record audio while doing speech recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765018/android-record-audio-while-doing-speech-recognition)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047433/record-save-audio-from-voice-recognition-intent

Comment: Google speech recognizer will give me audio file also but Quality of a audio file is very poor so i want to use third party library for speech recognisation i am familier with nuance speech recognisation , but getting same error with nuance , help me out to fix this issue

Comment: it seems to be not possible

Comment: yes it needs two mics in device to perform both operation on same time